# Update SQL Records in Drupal

Tags: sql, drupal

I need to update 50K records by changing the status of comments (turning read & read/write into disabled) and want to make sure my SQL statement is correct:

```
$query = "UPDATE node.nid AS nid, node.comment AS node_comment, node.type AS node_type
        SET node.comment = '0'
        WHERE (node.type in ('article', 'blog', 'event')) 
        AND  (node.comment in ('1','2'))";

$total = 0;
$count = 0;
while ($query_result = db_query($query)){
    $count++;
    $total++;
    if($count>200){
        $count = 0;
        sleep(300);
    }    
}
echo "Updated records:" . $total;
```

I added a periodic pause in there so it doesn't kill the server.  Does this look ok?

Comment: I think it's probably a better idea to backup your database and test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the UPDATE to just node node and that worked.